# How to display string as xml in jsp page

Tags: java, html, xml, jsp, struts2

Im working on Struts2 project, In action class im passing string to jsp page. I want to display that string content as xml in jsp page.

jsp page :  **response.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
    <s:property value="sampleStr" />
```

Action class : **ResponseAction**

```
public class ResponseAction extends ActionSupport {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
public String sampleStr;

public String execute() throws IOException {
    String responseStr = readStringFile();
    setSampleStr(responseStr);
    return SUCCESS;
}

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
public String readStringFile() throws IOException{
      String xmlStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n"+
              "<response>"+ "$$" +
              "</response>";
     InputStream inputStream = XmlFormatter.class.getResourceAsStream("/sample.txt");
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-16")));
        String s = "";
        List list = new ArrayList();
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(line);
        }
        for (Object s1: list) {
            s= s + s1;
        }
        xmlStr =   xmlStr.replace("$$", s);
        return xmlStr;

}


public String getSampleStr() {
    return sampleStr;
}

public void setSampleStr(String sampleStr) {
    this.sampleStr = sampleStr;
}
}
```

**Struts.xml :**

```
<package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">
  <action name="PEConsolidation" class="com.metlife.ibit.pe.web.controller.actions.ResponseAction">
  <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
    <result name="success">/WEB-INF/jsps/response.jsp</result>
  </action>
</package>
```

When i looks response.jsp, it display return string as text. please anyone help to display as xml content?

Comment: If you want it to be *interpreted* as XML you need to set the content disposition, with the caveat that users/browsers will handle XML content based on whatever its set up to do. If you just want it as plain text, e.g., not syntax-colored, just don't return it as HTML, but as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

`s:property` has built-in escaping functionality for HTML, JavaScript and XML.
By default it escapes HTML.

I think what you want to do is no escaping at all:

```
<s:property value="sampleStr" escapeHtml="false" />
```

You should also check the http headers of the response (`"content-type: text/html"` would be wrong in your case).

Instead of using a jsp, you could look into using a different result type, maybe write your own one.

https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/result-types.html

Answer (score 0):

I think that the browser is trying to interpret the XML tags as HTML tags and, failing to do so, is ignoring them.

You will need to replace each < and > character to `&amp;lt;` and `&amp;gt;` respectively. You can use very useful `String.replaceAll()` method in Java API's.

Additionally, you can check this [Oracle's page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/webappdev2-140046.html) out. It would be very helpful in your **development process using JSP with XML technologies**.